# react-intl: TypeError: A message must be provided as a String or AST if using nested json messages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I see errors in the console when using `react-intl` with nested json messages:

```
[React Intl] Error formatting message: "App.filter.dateRange" for locale: "en"
TypeError: A message must be provided as a String or AST.
```

But UI working correctly. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

#### messages (en.json)

```json
{
  "App.folderChooser.text": "Select folder to parse",
  "App.filter.dateRange": {
    "today": "Today",
    "thisWeek": "This Week",
    "thisMonth": "This Month"
  }
}
```

#### component (DateRangeSelector.js)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

export default ({ isDisabled, onChangeDateRange }) => (
  <FormattedMessage id="App.filter.dateRange">
    {({ today, thisWeek, thisMonth }) => (
      <DatePicker.RangePicker
        disabled={isDisabled}
        onChange={onChangeDateRange}
        ranges={{
          [today]: [moment().startOf('day'), moment().endOf('day')],
          [thisWeek]: [moment().startOf('week'), moment().endOf('week')],
          [thisMonth]: [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
        }}
      />
    )}
  </FormattedMessage>
);
```

#### Root component (App.js)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { LocaleProvider } from 'antd';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

import Header from './Header';
import Content from './Content';
import Footer from './Footer';

import './App.css';

const App = ({ antdLocale, appLocale }) => (
  <LocaleProvider locale={antdLocale} key={antdLocale.locale}>
    <IntlProvider
      locale={appLocale.locale}
      messages={appLocale.messages}
      textComponent={React.Fragment}
      defaultLocale="en"
    >
      <div className="app">
        <div className="app__header">
          <Header />
        </div>
        <div className="app__content">
          <Content />
        </div>
        <div className="app__footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </IntlProvider>
  </LocaleProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Project sources if need: https://github.com/trofivan/myq-jobs-archive-parser

Comment: I think, my implementation working correctly in the UI because of side-effect and I should use messages in the flat list. But I do not understand how to provide 3 props in my component eg today, thisWeek, thisMonth.

Answer (score 0):

Full discussion here: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/1161

Messages should be on a flat list:

```
{
  "App.filter.dateRange.today": "Today",
  "App.filter.dateRange.thisWeek": "This Week",
  "App.filter.dateRange.thisMonth": "This Month",
}
```

Use HOC (Higher-Order Component) for DateRangeSelector-component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import { injectIntl } from 'react-intl';

const DateRangeSelector = ({ isDisabled, onChangeDateRange, intl }) => (
  <DatePicker.RangePicker
    disabled={isDisabled}
    onChange={onChangeDateRange}
    ranges={{
      [intl.formatMessage({ id: 'App.filter.dateRange.today' })]: [
        moment().startOf('day'),
        moment().endOf('day')
      ],
      [intl.formatMessage({ id: 'App.filter.dateRange.thisWeek' })]: [
        moment().startOf('week'),
        moment().endOf('week')
      ],
      [intl.formatMessage({ id: 'App.filter.dateRange.thisMonth' })]: [
        moment().startOf('month'),
        moment().endOf('month')
      ]
    }}
  />
);

export default injectIntl(DateRangeSelector);
```